Reducedness of fixed point Scheme under action of reductive Group
Let $X$ be an affine variety over $\mathbb{C}$ by which I mean a reduced affine scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$. (If it makes it easier I'm happy to consider only irreducible ones) together with an action of a reductive algebraic group $G$. Let $\mathbb{C}[X]$ be the coordinate ring.
The action of $G$ on $X$ then induces an action on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ by $g \cdot f(x) := f(g^{-1}x)$.
One can then consider the fixed points $X^H := \operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{C}[X]/I_G)$ where $I_G$ is the ideal generated by the set $\{f-g \cdot f \mid g\in G, \ f\in C[X]\}$. Then $X^H$ will still be an affine scheme of finite type although in general it will not be irreducible and by Fogarty J. "Fixed Point Schemes" example 6.3 it also need not be reduced. The example he gives shows that even the action of a one dimensional Torus does not need to preserve reducedness for the fixed points.
I would be interested to know whether there is a criterion on the group such that the fixed points are reduced.
For example in Fogartys paper some statements are proven under the hypothesis that there exists no nontrivial morphism $G \to G_{m}$ but I can't see anything about reducedness in there.
I would also be interested to know whether something can be said about reducedness in the case of a finite group, or even a cyclic group. In the examples I've managed to compute this seems to hold at least for cyclic groups but I cannot imagine a proof at the moment.
Furthermore I would also be happy to consider restrictions on the variety in particular normality could be assumed for my intended application.
Many Thanks in advance

Have you looked at Proposition A.8.10 in Appendix A of (the published version of) Conrad--Gabber--Prasad's book Pseudo-reductive group schemes?

@AlexYoucis Thanks for the reference! As far as I can see this only tells me something when the original variety was smooth? Maybe I misunderstand the statement in the book and there is a criterion about some smooth morphism that I could attach to any reduced variety? I should have mentioned in the question that I'm particularly interested in the case where the variety is not necessarily smooth. (By a result of Fogarty or your reference the fixed points under the action of a reductive group on a smooth variety are always smooth and hence reduced in this case.)
